# Python Running Increasingly Slower, Garbage Collection Issue?

Tags: python, performance, garbage-collection

So I have code that grabs a list of files from a directory that initially had over 14 millions files. This is a hex-core machine with 20 GB RAM running Ubuntu 14.04 desktop and just grabbing a list of files takes hours - I haven't actually timed it.

Over the past week or so I've run code that doesn't nothing more than gather this list of files, open each file to determine when it was created, and move it to a directory based on the month and year it was created. (The files have been both scp'd and rsync'd so the timestamp the OS provides is meaningless at this point, hence opening the file.)

When I first started running this loop it was moving 1000 files in about 90 seconds. Then after several hours like this that 90 seconds became 2.5 min, then 4, then 5, then 9, and eventually 15 min. So I shut it down and started over.

I noticed that today once it was done gathering a list of over 9 millions files that moving 1000 files took 15 min right off the bat. I just shut the process down again and rebooted the machine because the time to move 1000 files had climbed to over 90 min.

I had hoped to find some means of doing a `while + list.pop()` style strategy to free memory as the loop progressed. Then found a couple of SO posts that said it could be done with `for i in list: ... list.remove(...)` but that this was a terrible idea.

Here's the code:

```
from basicconfig.startup_config import *

arc_dir = '/var/www/data/visits/'

def step1_move_files_to_archive_dirs(files):
  """

  :return:
  """

  cntr = 0
  for f in files:
      cntr += 1

      if php_basic_files.file_exists(f) is False:
          continue

      try:
          visit = json.loads(php_basic_files.file_get_contents(f))
      except:
          continue

      fname = php_basic_files.basename(f)

      try:
          dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(visit['Entrance Time'])
      except KeyError:
          continue

      mYr = dt.strftime("%B_%Y")

      # Move the lead to Monthly archive
      arc_path = arc_dir + mYr + '//'
      if not os.path.exists(arc_path):
          os.makedirs(arc_path, 0777)

      if not os.path.exists(arc_path):
          print "Directory: {} was not created".format(arc_path)
      else:
          # Move the file to the archive
          newFile = arc_path + fname
          #print "File moved to {}".format(newFile)
          os.rename(f, newFile)

      if cntr % 1000 is 0:
          print "{} files moved ({})".format(cntr, datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).isoformat())

def step2_combine_visits_into_1_file():
  """

  :return:
  """

  file_dirs = php_basic_files.glob(arc_dir + '*')

  for fd in file_dirs:
    arc_files = php_basic_files.glob(fd + '*.raw')
    arc_fname = arc_dir + php_basic_str.str_replace('/', '', php_basic_str.str_replace(arc_dir, '', fd)) + '.arc'

    try:
      arc_file_data = php_basic_files.file_get_contents(arc_fname)
    except:
      arc_file_data = {}

    for f in arc_files:
      uniqID = moduleName = php_adv_str.fetchBefore('.', php_basic_files.basename(f))

      if uniqID not in arc_file_data:
        visit = json.loads(php_basic_files.file_get_contents(f))
        arc_file_data[uniqID] = visit

    php_basic_files.file_put_contents(arc_fname, json.dumps(arc_file_data))


def main():
  """

  :return:
  """

  files = php_basic_files.glob('/var/www/html/ver1/php/VisitorTracking/data/raw/*')
  print "Num of Files: {}".format(len(files))

  step1_move_files_to_archive_dirs(files)
  step2_combine_visits_into_1_file()
```

Notes:

basicconfig is essentially a bunch of constants I have for the environment and a few commonly used libraries like all the php_basic_* libraries. (I used PHP for years before picking up Python so I built a library to mimic the more common functions I used in order to be up and running with Python faster.)

The step1 def is as far as the program gets so far. The step2 def could, and likely should, be run in parallel. However, I figured I/O was the bottleneck and doing even more of it in parallel would likely slow all functions down a lot more. (I have been tempted to rsync the archive directories to another machine for aggregation thus getting parallel speed without the I/O bottleneck but figured the rsync would also be quite slow.)

The files themselves are all 3 Kb each so not very large.

----- Final Thoughts -------

Like I said, it doesn't appear, to me at least, that any data is being stored from each file opening. Therefore memory should not be an issue. However, I do notice that only 1.2 GB of RAM is being used right now and over 12 GB of was being used before. A big chunk of that 12 could be storing 14 million file names and paths. I've only just started the processing again so for next several hours python will be gathering a list of files and that list isn't in memory yet.

So I was wondering if there was a garbage collection issue or something else I was missing. Why is it slowing down as it progresses through the loop?

Comment: Have you tried not sticking 14 million objects in to memory all at once? Perhaps a generator would be a better fit here?

Comment: A garbage collection issue is very unlikely for a program like this one. Still, you can use `import gc; gc.disable()` to disable automatic collection. (Reference counting will still be used, but it does not introduce incremental slowdowns characteristic of sweeping collectors.) Also, I would recommend to get rid of the PHP emulation layer, which slows down execution and makes the program harder to review by Python experts.

Comment: The glob does grab all 14 million (now 9 million) and return them as one giant list. Rebooting the machine has returned to a fast state. In the middle of the night the script was moving 1000 files in less than a minute. It has since climbed to just over 90 seconds to move 1000 files. Before the reboot it took over 2 hrs to move 1000 files. GC was just a guess I'm also wondering if the OS and I/O issue is at play. For all the comments about the 14 M list it doesn't grow during the execution of step 1, as such that list shouldn't slow down the execution of step1 as it progresses thru the list.

Comment: Sorry for the code lacking comments. Typically I write a lot of comments but this code is really just meant to reorganize the files and directory structure once. Then the newer files will either get some similar code to reorganize them or I'll have them saved to the correct archive folder in the first place.

Comment: I haven't used generators yet so I'm having a hard time seeing how a generator could be used in this instance. Googling didn't help but maybe I was asking the wrong questions. The OS bombs when I ask for a list of files from this directory but for some reason Python does not.

Comment: I would recommend to retarget this issue as not Python- and GC-specific: it is very likely a filesystem issue (which filesystem is that?).  Depending on the implementation and options, this could invoke quadratic behavior: every os.rename() needs to locate the source file name to remove from the huge directory, and it might take a time that is proportional to the number of entries before in the directory---including already-deleted entries.

Answer (score 0):

**`step1_move_files_to_archive_dirs`**:

Here's some reasons Step 1 might be taking longer than you expected...

The response to any exception during Step 1 is to `continue` to the next file.  If you have any corrupted data files, they will stay in the filesystem forever, increasing the amount of work this function has to do next time (and the next, and the next...).

You are reading in every file and converting it from JSON to a `dict`, just to extract one date.  So *everything* is read and converted at least once.  If you control the creation of these files, it might be worth storing this value in the filename or in a separate index / log, so you don't have to go searching for that value again later.

If the input directories and output / archive directories are on separate filesystems, `os.rename(f, newFile)` can't just *rename* the file, but has to *copy* every byte from the source filesystem to the target filesystem.  So either every file is near-instantaneously renamed, or *every* input file is slowly copied.

PS:  It's weird that this function double-checks things like whether the input file still exists, or if `os.makedirs` worked, but then allows any exception from `os.rename` to crash you mid-loop.

**`step2_combine_visits_into_1_file`**:

All your file I/O is hidden inside that PHP library, but it looks to this PHP outsider like you're trying to store in RAM the *contents* of all the files in each subdirectory.  Then, you accumulate all those contents inside some smaller number of archive files, while preserving (most of?) the data that was already there.  Not only is that probably slow to begin with, it will get slower as time goes on.

Function code mostly replaced by comments:

```python3
file_dirs =  # arch_dir/* --- Maybe lots, maybe only a few.
for fd in file_dirs:
    arc_files =  # arch_dir/subdir*.raw or maybe arch_dir/subdir/*.raw.
    arc_fname =  # subdir.arc
    arc_file_data =  # Contents of JSON file subdir.arc, as a dict.
    for f in arc_files:  # The *.raw files.
        uniqID =  # String based on f's filename.
        if uniqID not in arc_file_data:
            # Add to arc_file_data the uniqID key, and the
            # _ entire contents_ of the .raw file as its value.
    php_basic_files.file_put_contents  # (...)
    # Convert the arc_file_data dict into one _massive_ string,
    # and replace the contents of the subdir.arc file.
```

Unless you have some maintenance job that periodically trims the `*.arc` files, you will eventually have the entire contents of all 14 million files (plus any older files) inside the `*.arc` files.  Each of those `.arc` files gets read into a `dict`, converted to a mega-string, *grown* (probably), and then written back to the filesystem.  That's a ton of I/O, even if the average `.arc` file isn't very big (which can only happen if there are *lots* of them).

Why do all this anyway?  By the start of Step 2, you've already got a unique ID for each `.raw` input file, and it's already *in the filename* --- so why not use the filesystem itself to store `/arch_dir/subdir/unique_id.json`?

If you really do need all this data in a few huge archives, that shouldn't require so much work.  The `.arc` files are little more than the unaltered contents of the `.raw` files, with bits of a JSON dictionary between them.  A simple shell script could slap that together without ever interpreting the JSON itself.

(If the values are not just JSON but *quoted* JSON, you would have to change whatever reads the `.arc` files to *not* un-quote those values.  But now I'm purely speculating, since I can only see some of what's happening.)

PS:  Am I missing something, or is `arc_files` a list of `*.raw` filenames.  Shouldn't it be `raw_files`?

**Other Comments**:

As others have noted, if your file-globbing function returns a mega-list of 14 million filenames, it would be vastly more memory-efficient as a generator that can `yield` one filename at a time.

Finally, you mentioned popping filenames off a `list` (although I don't see that in your code)...  There is a *huge* time penalty for inserting or removing the first element of a large list --- `del my_list[0]` or `my_list.pop(0)` or `my_list.insert(0, something)` --- because items 1 though n-1 all have to be copied one index toward 0.  That turns an O(*n*) operation into O(*n***2)... again, if that's in your code anywhere.

Comment: step2 isn't yet running. It only runs after step1 is complete and step has never been run to completion. However, step2's arc_file_data is meant to be an aggregation of all the files in a given month_year archive directory. So it won't have all 14 M just the files from a given month_year combo. That still looks like it could be as big as 1 M though so I'm looking into way of reducing the size. Specifically by creating lists of redundant data - user agent strings - and replacing that data with an integer for each visit.

Comment: As far as step1 goes, I let the code fail on os.rename because I've had issues with os.rename deleting files in Ubuntu 14.04. It typically does it silently though so letting it crash the function isn't much of an issue. The main purpose behind step2 is to allow me to then zip up the archive directories while still having access to the data in those files. As far as going forward is concerned, this 14 M files have been accumulated over a couple of years. If I simply run this archiving script once an hour it will complete in seconds so I'm not concerned with renaming the files.